# Multer single function not working. Unable to upload file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I am facing issue while file upload in express.js with multer.

*I have written below code in my route.js:*

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});

module.exports = function(router) {
    router.post('/route/file', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
        // this is not called..
        console.log('this should be called');
    });
}
```

**It's strange in my windows it's working fine. But in my MacBook same code isn't working.**